# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Virtual Hosts

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, virtualhost

I have started to test a migration from PHP 7.0 to 7.4 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Worked out some issues with yum package names. But im having an issue with my old virtual hosts situation.

Previously this was in a .conf file in .ebextensions:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      NameVirtualHost *:80
      NameVirtualHost *:443

      <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dashboard.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.dashboard.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
      </VirtualHost>
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName dashboard.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.dashboard.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
      </VirtualHost>
      <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName txtlocal.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.txtlocal.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/includes/txtlocal_inbound/
      </VirtualHost>
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName txtlocal.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.txtlocal.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/includes/txtlocal_inbound/
      </VirtualHost>
```

Now im having issues getting those virtual hosts to work. What do I need to change for PHP 7.4 to work with my virtual hosts? I can see that the server changed to nginx, is there a way to do it in a nginx config file? I can't seem to find anything in the docs for AWS Elastic Beanstalk...

Answer (score -1):

Yo are trying to use virtual hosts instead of server/locations. AWS used Apache, but in modern versions they are deploying aplications with NGINX. I'm facing the same upgrade situation.

Read this if you want to understand how to define "virtual servers" in NGINX:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

This may also help:
https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-virtual-host

You can find NGINX conf file using

```
nginx -V
```

Note mayus V